# ros2 run rviz on remote machine

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, network, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm quite new approaching ROS2, I'm wondering if it is possible to run Rviz on a machine and run a set of nodes on another having them connected by a network, I remember that on ROS1 it was possible thanks by setting ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP.

I didn't found anything on ROS2. Do you know if it is possible?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363258/ros2-run-rviz-on-remote-machine/) by [luca.fancellu](https://answers.ros.org/users/53590/luca.fancellu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible. In fact it's easier then w/ ros1. Just make sure both machines are on the same network and are using the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID (default is 0, so should work fine by default unless you changed something)

---

Originally posted by [paul.frivold](https://answers.ros.org/users/60825/paul.frivold/) with karma: 46 on 2020-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca.fancellu](https://answers.ros.org/users/53590/luca.fancellu/) on 2020-10-22**:
To add more information to this answer, when running ROS2 on a container, just launch it with the

```
-e ROS_DOMAIN_ID=<number>
```

argument and it will launch ROS2 and setup everything.
Otherwise in the shell just do:

```
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=<number>
source /opt/ros/<version>/setup.bash
```